# Preventing submodule duplication while maintaining separability and allowing project composition

Tags: git, cmake

I have been using submodules to include projects inside "super-projects".
I am running into an annoyance though where I have the same submodule included several times in one super project.

For example, say I have a project called `Helpers`.
Then I have a project, `GeometryHelpers`, that includes `Helpers` as a submodule.
Then I have another project called `AlgebraHelpers` that includes `Helpers` as a submodule.

So far so good, this lets me reuse my `Helpers` code.

However, now say I have a project called `Math` that has `GeometryHelpers` and `AlgebraHelpers` as submodules.
Now I have two copies of `Helpers` (`Math/GeometryHelpers/Helpers` and `Math/AlgebraHelpers/Helpers`).
If I have to change something in `Helpers`, I then have to make sure to not forget to update it in both places, or I could expect things to be out of sync.

My current update process if something in `Helpers` changes (which happens regularly) is:

```
cd Math/GeometryHelpers/Helpers; git pull
cd ..; git add -u; git commit; git push # update the pointer to Helpers in GeometryHelpers
cd ../AlgebraHelpers/Helpers; git pull; 
cd ..; git add -u; git push # update the pointer to Helpers in AlgebraHelpers
cd ..; git add -u; git push # update the pointers to AlgebraHelpers and GeometryHelpers in Math
```

It seems like the ideal case would be to have Math/Helpers, and have `Math/AlgebraHelpers` and `Math/GeometryHelpers` use the same `Math/Helpers`.
But to setup something like this, it seems like it would be hard to maintain the ability to build `AlgebraHelpers` in a standalone way (i.e. not inside Math).

I don't really want to build libraries and install them on the system somewhere because when I am working in `GeometryHelpers` and want to update something in `Helpers`, I'd have to go open the `Helpers` project, build the library, and install it to wherever `GeometryHelpers` is looking for it.
That is not a particularly smooth process, especially since `Helpers` is changing frequently.

Is there a better way to handle this?
I am using CMake as my build system and all of these projects are c++ projects.

Comment: Can't you solve this on the CMake-level by writing your CMakeLists, such that only a single Helpers is used in Math?

Comment: @Andre Yes, that is what I do now, but it just seems very dangerous. If I get one path wrong in a giant list of paths, I could be using the wrong code and not know it.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to stop recording the Helpers SHA1 at the `(Algebra|Geometry)Helpers` levels (ie don't initialize the submodule there) and record it at the Math level (add `Helpers` as a submodule there).
But that isn't practical, as the various commits of `(Algebra|Geometry)Helpers` won't ever know what SHA1 of `Helpers` there were supposed to use.

The other option would be to check if the script [`git new-workdir`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/workdir/git-new-workdir) (in contrib of any git distribution since git1.7.10) could help avoiding the duplication of `Helpers` submodule.
See "[Duplicate submodules with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4116331/6309)".

You would still need to commit and push each parent repos, but at least you would use only one `Helpers` across all parent repos.