# How to share a common git submodule within a superproject

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am organizing all of my dotfiles into a git super-project and putting any similar files into submodules so I can pull them out individually if I need to. The issue I have run into is that I would like to have a common aliases file (and perhaps others) for both bash and zsh. Ideally I would like to have these common files be included if I choose to clone just one of bash/zsh on a system.

Right now I have the submodules `~/.bash` and `~/.zsh`. What would be nice is a `~/.shell` submodule that is actually a submodule of both `~/.bash` and `~/.zsh`. Can something like this be done? If so, how?

I am trying to avoid doing something like `~/.bash/shell` and `~/.zsh/shell` and I don't want to have to remember to update one everytime I change the other. One possible solution might be to hard link `~/.bash/shell` and `~/.zsh/shell`, but then if I clone my full dotfile repository onto a new machine, I will need to set up this hard link again.

Hopefully I have explained by question well enough. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** I just found some similar stack exchange questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115817/duplicate-submodules-with-git) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419498/git-nested-submodules-and-dependencies)). It sounds like hard linking or creating a special bash-only and zsh-only super project might be the only real options. I don't really like the multiple super project option as I feel it is too much to keep updated. Is there another option that I'm still missing?

Comment: yes, you read it right, this is impossible without external tools.

Answer (score 0):

git supports soft links. So instead of hard-linking, you could just soft-link the files using `ln -s`.

Comment: I don't think soft links will work for me as I want the flexibility of checking out only one repository or the other.