# How to add submodule without adding its own submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-clone

I have a project X which already has submodules A, B and C. Now I want to add submodule D but it also contains its own submodule A. Is there any way to prevent having 2 As in the whole tree? If someone clones my main project (recursively) I want it to contain A, B, C and D without its own A.

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144406/how-to-make-shallow-git-submodules?noredirect=1&lq=1) is similar however the solution (`--depth`) limits amount of downloaded history while I want to limit "submodule recursion depth".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1419498/7976758, https://stackoverflow.com/a/4116331/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+duplicate

Comment: I like the first one, but I'm not sure how to remove a submodule - should I create `A'` by cloning it, removing its own submodules and make a commit in `A` or `Core`? Is that how it works?

Comment: I'd first try symlinks — after removing duplicate submodules worktrees — in hope there would be no changes visible to git so no commit required.

Comment: Symlinks do not work. The `git new-workdir` script wants to use actual `ln -s` command, which will not work on Windows clones, even under Git Bash (which implements `ln -s` as `cp`). The second option however - seems completely broken - git goes mad when it sees 2 different submodules with same origins, it behaves like code with data races - there is only 1 instance of the duplicated repo (in one of possible places) but this place is different depending how did you clone/fetch/work-on root project.